# Separar metodos da API da configuração do Server

Tags: javascript, api, mongodb, express.js, require

Fiz uma API no express com mongodb, como primeira etapa tenho somente métodos de autenticação de usuário. Como mostrado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso tem as configurações do servidor

```
// Import Packages
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const allowCors = require('./config/cors');

const app = express()
const URLBase = 3003

// Config JSON
app.use(express.json());

// Configure Cors
app.use(allowCors);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token')
    next();
});

// Models
const User = require('./models/user');
```

Start do servidor:

```
// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(URLBase)
        console.log(`Connected to the database at port ${URLBase}`)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Tudo isso está em um único arquivo app.js, eu gostaria de separar as funções em um arquivo separado, por exemplo: as imagens da função estar em um arquivo "UserMethods.js". Como fazer isso? Obrigado

Eu tentei dessa forma mas nao funcionou:

```
const Usermethods = require('./UserMethods')
app.use('UserMethods')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver é utilizando a classe Router do express.

Neste exemplo estou supondo que quer colocar as rotas existentes organizadas em outro arquivo, para depois importar estas rotas no  `app.js`.

Desta forma temos que declarar um novo arquivo e usar a classe `express.Router`.

***rotas.js***

```
const User = require('./models/user');
const router = require('express').Router();

checkToken = (req,  res, next) => {
   //...
}
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({msg: "server up and running"});
}
router.get('/users', checkToken, (req, res) => {
   //...
});
router.post('/auth/register', async (req, res) => {
   //...
});
//declarar as outras rotas...

module.exports = router;
```

Depois em seu arquivo `app.js` você deve importar o seu arquivo de rotas em seu aplicativo express da seguinte forma:

***app.js***

```
// Import Packages
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const allowCors = require('./config/cors');

const app = express()
const URLBase = 3003

// Config JSON
app.use(express.json());

// Configure Cors
app.use(allowCors);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token')
    next();
});

app.use(require('./rotas.js')); //<-- Usar as rotas declaradas
```

Ou pode tentar fazer da maneira que tentou:

***app.js***

```
// Import Packages
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const allowCors = require('./config/cors');
const Usermethods = require('./rotas.js'); //<-- importar as rotas declaradas


const app = express()
const URLBase = 3003

// Config JSON
app.use(express.json());

// Configure Cors
app.use(allowCors);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token')
    next();
});
app.use(Usermethods); //<-- Usar as rotas declaradas
```

Para mais informações sobre como declarar e utilizar as rotas consulte a [documentação de rotas do express](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/guide/routing.html).